# ArchLinux how to setup English Language with german keyboardlayout

Tags: arch-linux, locale, keyboard-layout

Can anyone explain me how to setup up ArchLinux to be completely in English except for the KeyboardLayout? (it should be de-latin1-nodeadkeys)

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_keyboard_layouts_in_X

Comment: so as locale I should use en-US and the keyboardlayout gets configured in the xorg.conf?

Comment: Precisely. That's how you'd do it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get system where your locale is en_US.UTF-8 (assuming you want utf-8, which is recommended) and keyboard layout in both X.Org and virtual consoles is de-latin1-nodeadkeys, do these steps:

- uncomment line "en_US.UTF-8" from `/etc/locale.gen`
  (e.g. `sed -i 's/#en_US.UTF-8/en-US.UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen`)
- `locale-gen`
- `echo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 > /etc/locale.conf`
- `localectl set-keymap de-latin1-nodeadkeys`
- `localectl set-x11-keymap de-latin1-nodeadkeys`

Sidenote: `localectl set-keymap` writes given keymap to `/etc/vconsole.conf` to variable `KEYMAP`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But here is the question: is `localectl set-keymap` is the same as manually edit `/etc/vconsole.conf` and set `KEYMAP=de-latin1-nodeadkeys`? By the way, is there analogue with `set-X11-keymap`?

Comment: Literally did everything step by step and it didn't work - keyboard is still en_US and not de_DE.

Comment: @rbaleksandar There's a typo. The lines in `/etc/locale.conf` and `/etc/locale.gen` should start with `en_US.UTF-8`, not `en-US.UTF-8`

Comment: Yeah, after looking for more information I came across the same conclusion. Thanks for sharing though!

Answer (score 2):

There are european standards that you may want to have on your system, like

- metric system
- 24h time format
- week starting with monday
- date in ISO-8601
- comma as decimal mark
- paper size A4
- euro as currency

If you want english language and also the above standards, you may want to consider to use danish english instead of us english. To do so, just generate and use the locale en_DK.UTF-8 instead of en_US.UTF-8.

To use german keyboard layout:

```
echo KEYMAP=de-latin1 > /etc/vconsole.conf
```

More about this can be found [in the german arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Arch_Linux_auf_Deutsch_stellen#Standardkonforme_Angaben).